# How to make my python script accepts multiple positional arguments?

Tags: python

Suppose that I would like my python program to accept 2 positional arguments:
1. The path to an input file 
2.The path to a word dictionary, which is also a txt file.

Can anyone teach me how to go about doing that?

Comment: `The path to a word dictionary, which is also a txt file.` what you mean here

Comment: what I just meant the second argument is for specifying the path to another txt file, which happens to be used as a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

print('Name of the script: {0}'.format(sys.argv[0]))

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    inputfile_path = sys.argv[1]
    dictionary_path = sys.argv[2]
    print('First parameter: {0}'.format(inputfile_path))
    print('Second parameter: {0}'.format(dictionary_path))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Comment: Yep, except for the redundant parentheses on the `if` condition, which I would recommend removing:-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli: Ooops, thanks - wrote too much Java in the last couple of weeks, going to remove it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague so I'm just going to answer what I think you meant.

I'll assume that you have a function as such:

```
def function(string1, string2):
''' string 1 and string2 are paths to an input file and a dictionary respectively'''
```

Now in general to read a file you use:

```
file1 = open(string1,'r')
# After opening the file you loop over lines to do what you need to. 
for line in file:
    # Do what you need to
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the input file so I'm going to leave it at that.

To load a dictionary from a string we use the `eval()` function. It actually runs a string. Now each line in the dictionary stored as a text file is a string so all you have to do is loop through the entire file (using the `for line in file` method from before) and run `eval` to get back a dictionary.

For example try this simple code:

```
#assume string2 is what you get back from the looping
string2 = str({'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139})

dic = eval(string2)

print dic
```

Hopefully I've pointed you in the right direction. Since I'm not sure what exactly you need to do, I can't really help you more.